# How to loop through using a foreach statement within my laravel blade view?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to loop through selected fields within my database and then post them to the blade view page. However I cannot return the data and it returns Undefined variable: posts error message.

I have tried multiple ways to return to the view e.g with->() and compact

Below is the function within my Controller which gets the posts and send them to the view.

```
public function getPosts()
{
  $posts = Posts::all();
  //  return view('profile', ['posts' => $posts]);

    //$profilePosts = Posts::paginate(10);
   return view('page.profile' , compact('posts'));

}
```

Below is my foreach statement within my blade view.

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)

{{$post->postContent}}

 @endforeach
```

the expected output should be a list of posts and the content which is stored in the database

Below is my Post model class

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Posts extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {

        //Relationship
        return $this->belongsTo("App\User");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the value being retrieved in the view, try dumping the $post in the controller , what does it show?

Comment: Why not `return view('page.profile' , ['posts' => $posts]);`

Comment: @Ibu it still returns undefined variable

Comment: @MVS it doesn't seem to retrieving any data , i've tried to echo $post but it does not display anything, any other suggestions?

Comment: In your controller before returning the view `dd($posts);` please

Comment: Have you included your model file here , App/Posts?

Comment: @MVS I will update my question description with my model file

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din nothing returns

Comment: Post the output as img please because it must not return view at all

Comment: The code samples you have provided does not have any error please, double check the flow of your code. Maybe your request going somewhere else. Instead of getPosts() method or may be.

Comment: check your routing that point to that view

Comment: @John try to add `protected $table = 'posts';` to Post model class.

Comment: how you check by `with()` please show that snippet

Comment: ``$post->postContent`` what is this ``postContent`` is that field exists in ``posts`` table??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all I found the problem with my code. firstly I included `protected $table = 'posts';` within my Posts Model class, advised by  @Jinal Somaiya. Then ensuring that I had the correct routes and included the below code in my PostsController index function

```
   $posts = Posts::all();



   return view('page.profile')->with('posts',$posts);
```

The above foreach statement in my question description is correct.

Thanks for everyones help!